# Проблема с Android проектом!

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Для создания проекта я использую код который я предварительно скопировал в документ. Для инициализации элемента я использую `findViewById(R.id.элемент)` 
При копировании листинга MainAtivity у меня после вставки в саму студию, или в другой класс с инициализацией виджетов, у меня буква R горит красным, студия не может понять в чем проблема. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает в чем дело.

Comment: Может забыли импортировать import com.your.package.R; ?

Comment: Проблема распространённая, бывает время от времени у всех, лечится чисткой проекта (Build - Clean project)  и/или удалением кэша.

Comment: @ИванТ R это встроенный класс андроидных ресурсов. Его не надо импортировать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, `R` не нужно импортировать только в том случае, когда пакет текущего класса совпадает с пакетом приложения или при использовании полного имени класса (с пакетом).

Comment: Если `R` подсвечивается красным, то он в другом пакете и не импортирован, или он не сгенерирован так как у Вас ещё не было ни одной удачной сборки, либо из-за ошибок в ресурсах. Сделайте `Rebuild project`, если грэдл выдаст ошибки - исправьте и повторите, до тех пор, пока сборка не закончится успешно.

Comment: та я попробовал `Clean project` и помогло)))